# How to prevent Fullcalendar events with the same timeperiod overlap?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, overlap, overlapping

I am currently using **Fullcalendar** by *Adam Shaw*. If I create two different events with the same time period fist the events are shown next to each other then after I refresh the page they are shown under each other which is the correct way I want to achieve.
Is there a way I can make this work without having to refresh the page?
If it helps I have a screenshot here:
[image]

After I refresh the page the new event(light pink) goes under the previous event(Dark pink). I would like to avoid the page refresh to correct this problem

Comment: You should post some code if you want people to help you... that said, have you tried this on a page with no other markup and minimal styling?

Comment: @RobertMunn I try to find some code. Yes, I tried but got the same result.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this ? @arvind http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotEventOverlap/

Comment: @MartijnWelkerYes I have done that, and it fixes the problem. The issue is that I need to refresh the page before the calendar is updated visually so the events don't overlap.